# I would like install R on my laptop Mac OS X version 10.13.1

Tags: r

I downloaded the version R 3.3.3 and I double click on it and it was installed, when i start up I get the following error, I searched in internet but I could not solve the problem, any help would be appreciated
the errors are

```
Durante la inicializaci'on - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
[R.app GUI 1.69 (7328) x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0]

WARNING: You're using a non-UTF8 locale, therefore only ASCII characters will work.
Please read R for Mac OS X FAQ (see Help) section 9 and adjust your system preferences accordingly.
[History restored from /Users/jesusbobadillanavarro/.Rapp.history]
```

I'm strating with this, i know less that zero, pls help, thinking that the explication to a kid, thank a lot

Comment: Those are not errors, they are warnings. Does R work after those warnings?

Comment: Look for the MAC FAQ document here: https://cran.r-project.org under the "Download R for (Mac) OS X".  They goto section 7 of the FAQ.